# How can a resolve issues relating to autosave, multiple instances, launcher and errors in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

Recently I have had problems with my Libreoffice on Ubuntu 12.10.
It does not seem to save changes in documents frequently and depending on what file I open 2 LibreOffices will be running and one of the icons will be where I put it and the other one very far down in the launcher. I suspect that they interfere with eachother in some way.
Also, if I then restart my computer - LibreOffice and LibreCalculate will be gone from the side panel and I have to get them from the "Home" folder again.
I have tried to uninstall them and install again but there is no change.

I typed in `libreoffice` in the terminal and got this:

```
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment! 
Please ensure that a JVM and the package libreoffice-java-common is installed.
If it is already installed then try removing ~/.libreoffice/3/user/config/javasettings_Linux_*.xml
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
```

Comment: Press ctrl+alt+t and type `libreoffice` and enter some documents, and try what you just mentioned problems with. Then, copy all the output in the terminal, and enter it in your post (edit your first post).

Answer (score 2):

If LibreOffice doesn't detect the Java runtime, you need to tell it where it is.

1. Open a LibreOffice program.
2. Menu: Tools --> Options
3. In the dialog: LibreOffice --> Java
4. Check use a java runtime environment if needed; use the Add button to add the location of your installed runtime.
5. Click OK

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    sudo apt-get install libreoffice libreoffice-java-common
```

Answer (score 0):

You could install a java environment with:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
```